# How can I retrieve the id generated by a MySQL Trigger using a model with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using a Trigger in MySQL to generate the id of a table instead of using an autoincrement field. The reason is because the id must have a check digit which is calculated when it’s inserted, based on the last id on the table.

The problem is that when I use $model->save() I don’t get the id generated and saved, as I get when using autoincrement fields. It always returns “0”.

Is there any way to retrieve the actual id that is saved in the database in this case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your trigger is configured as **AFTER INSERT ON**. The reason you're getting the id 0 is that the **INSERT** command and the **TRIGGER** execution are 2 different DB transactions and id column is set to 0 as default. I haven't tested it but try to get the id with MySql PDO object.

```
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

And if it doesn't work. Just get the last inserted model.

```
$id = Model::latest()->first()->id;
```

There may be a better solution.

Comment: Yeah! `Model::latest()->first()` did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel model refresh:

```
$model->refresh()
```

after saving to DB. You'll have the whole model there.

Comment: I've already tried it. As I said, the id returned when saved (after an insert) is always "0". Therefore, it raises an error when using refresh, because it tries to select the item with id 0.